# Need help with Conditional Column Formatting on SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a Choice column (Yes,No) and the default value is blank.  I can get the Yes/No values easily and change the colors (Green/Red) but I need the 'Blank' value to be white. I need help with this 3rd condition. The column is called "Move_x0020_batching_x0020_proces"  I have my code below:

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    "padding": "0 2px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": {
      "operator": ":",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": "==",
          "operands": [
            "[$Move_x0020_batching_x0020_proces]",
            true
          ]
        },
        "sp-css-backgroundColor-successBackground",
        "sp-css-backgroundColor-errorBackground"
      ]
    }
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "line-height": "16px",
        "height": "14px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "==",
              "operands": [
                "[$Move_x0020_batching_x0020_proces]",
                true
              ]
            },
            "",
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
        "padding": "0 3px"
      },
      "txtContent": "=if(@currentField == true, 'Yes', if(@currentField == false,'No',''))",
      "attributes": {
        "class": {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "==",
              "operands": [
                "[$Move_x0020_batching_x0020_proces]",
                true
              ]
            },
            "",
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is the data type of your column? Is it a Choice or Yes/No (Boolean) column?

Comment: It is a Text (Choice) field as in "Yes" or "No" with a default of blank. So also need to check for blank and Not color it at all.

Comment: It's like I need 3 IF statements at: "if(@currentField" I think

Answer (score 0):

To check blank value for choice column you can use below condition:

```
=if([$ChoiceCol], 'Not Blank', 'Blank')
```

**OR**

```
=if([$ChoiceCol] == '', 'Blank', 'Not Blank')
```

Comment: How would that look on this line, assuming this is where to put it?
"txtContent": "=if(@currentField == true, 'Yes', if(@currentField == false,'No',''))",

Comment: Are you adding this JSON on same choice column? Or is it another column and you need merge these two conditions (old one you are using and the new one I am suhh8)?

Comment: I figured it out and posted my answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Here is the code to share with anyone else

```
    {
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    "padding": "0 2px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": {
      "operator": ":",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": "==",
          "operands": [
            "[$Move_x0020_batching_x0020_proces]",
            "YES"
          ]
        },
        "sp-css-backgroundColor-successBackground30",
        {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "==",
              "operands": [
                "[$Move_x0020_batching_x0020_proces]",
                ""
              ]
            },
            "",
            {
              "operator": ":",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "==",
                  "operands": [
                    "[$Move_x0020_batching_x0020_proces]",
                    "NO"
                  ]
                },
                "sp-css-backgroundColor-blockingBackground30",
                "sp-css-backgroundColor-neutralBackground"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "line-height": "16px",
        "height": "14px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "==",
              "operands": [
                "[$Move_x0020_batching_x0020_proces]",
                "YES"
              ]
            },
            "",
            {
              "operator": ":",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "==",
                  "operands": [
                    "[$Move_x0020_batching_x0020_proces]",
                    ""
                  ]
                },
                "",
                {
                  "operator": ":",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "==",
                      "operands": [
                        "[$Move_x0020_batching_x0020_proces]",
                        "NO"
                      ]
                    },
                    "",
                    ""
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
        "padding": "0 3px"
      },
      "txtContent": "[$Move_x0020_batching_x0020_proces]",
      "attributes": {
        "class": {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "==",
              "operands": [
                "[$Move_x0020_batching_x0020_proces]",
                "YES"
              ]
            },
            "",
            {
              "operator": ":",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "==",
                  "operands": [
                    "[$Move_x0020_batching_x0020_proces]",
                    ""
                  ]
                },
                "",
                {
                  "operator": ":",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "==",
                      "operands": [
                        "[$Move_x0020_batching_x0020_proces]",
                        "NO"
                      ]
                    },
                    "",
                    ""
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```